# Obtain Azure Log Analytics Free tier

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I have one Azure subscription that I can create only 10 Log Analytic workspace that have free tier

I another subscription I cannot create any

Any ideas?

I dont know what can I do

Comment: You can try your luck by opening a billing support ticket. But very much assume the answer will be: you cannot

Comment: Do you have any concerns about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can get `Azure Log Analytics` by rest api([Log Analytics REST API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/#access-log-analytics-data)).

But you use `Free tier`, there will be restrictions in log analytics.

> The Free pricing tier is a legacy pricing tier which is available for trying Azure Log Analytics. It has a data cap of 500 MB/day and only 7 days of data retention, so it is intended only for testing and is not to be used for production deployments. Note that moving to the Free tier from any other tier with longer retention will result in data older than 7 days being deleted.

[image]

Comment: the free option doesnt appear for me